# Center not everything in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

Here is my HTML Code:

```css
.kobel_perm {
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
}

.kobel_input_cont {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:center;
}

.kobelK {
 padding: 5px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7ef6a9, #86a8e7);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.kobel_perm input {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input::placeholder {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button] {
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button]:hover, .kobel_in input[type=button]:focus {
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
 animation: color_change 1s;
 background-color: #7ef6a9;
 color: #212121;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
 0% {
  background-color: #00251d1d;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #7ef6a9;
  color: #212121;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='kobel_perm'>
    <p class="kobelK">Kobeltage</p>
    <div class="kobel_input_cont">
         <input type="text" id="kobel_weekday" name="kobel_weekday" placeholder="Wochentag">
         <input type="text" id="kobel_date" name="kobel_date" placeholder="Datum">
         <input type="text" id="kobel_topic" name="kobel_topic" placeholder="Thema">
         <input type="text" id="kobel_host" name="kobel_host" placeholder="Kobelwirte">
         <input type="button" value="Kobel hinzufügen" onclick="addKobel()">
         <input type="button" value="Kobel entfernen" onclick="removeKobel()">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the result I get:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/37kor9k1lccctl3/look.PNG?dl=0
When you have a look at the image you see the inputs are not centered horizontally. I search a way to fix that because I only want to center the inputs, not the text "Kobeltage" above.
~filip

Comment: You want to set placeholders in center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for: `text-align:center`

Just add that property to the div containing your inputs:

```
.kobel_input_cont {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to center your placeholders?
Center them with pseudoelement, like so:

```css
.kobel_perm {
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
}

.kobel_input_cont {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:center;
}

.kobelK {
 padding: 5px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7ef6a9, #86a8e7);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.kobel_perm input {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input::placeholder {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button] {
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button]:hover, .kobel_in input[type=button]:focus {
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
 animation: color_change 1s;
 background-color: #7ef6a9;
 color: #212121;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
 0% {
  background-color: #00251d1d;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #7ef6a9;
  color: #212121;
 }
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class='kobel_perm'>
                      <p class="kobelK">Kobeltage</p>
                      <div class="kobel_input_cont">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_weekday" name="kobel_weekday" placeholder="Wochentag">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_date" name="kobel_date" placeholder="Datum">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_topic" name="kobel_topic" placeholder="Thema">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_host" name="kobel_host" placeholder="Kobelwirte">
                        <input type="button" value="Kobel hinzufügen" onclick="addKobel()">
                        <input type="button" value="Kobel entfernen" onclick="removeKobel()">
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set placeholder in center then you just need to write,

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}
```

This will bring your placeholder in center

```css
.kobel_perm {
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0d0d0d;
}

.kobel_input_cont {
 justify-content: center;
 align-items:center;
}

.kobelK {
 padding: 5px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #7ef6a9, #86a8e7);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.kobel_perm input {
    width: 95%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input::placeholder {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button] {
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
}

.kobel_perm input[type=button]:hover, .kobel_in input[type=button]:focus {
 border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
 animation: color_change 1s;
 background-color: #7ef6a9;
 color: #212121;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
 0% {
  background-color: #00251d1d;
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #7ef6a9;
  color: #212121;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class='kobel_perm'>
                      <p class="kobelK">Kobeltage</p>
                      <div class="kobel_input_cont">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_weekday" name="kobel_weekday" placeholder="Wochentag">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_date" name="kobel_date" placeholder="Datum">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_topic" name="kobel_topic" placeholder="Thema">
                        <input type="text" id="kobel_host" name="kobel_host" placeholder="Kobelwirte">
                        <input type="button" value="Kobel hinzufügen" onclick="addKobel()">
                        <input type="button" value="Kobel entfernen" onclick="removeKobel()">
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your css

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align:center`

[Here is the working code.](https://jsbin.com/wuguxohome/2/edit?html,css,output)